# How to get the inline style border-color from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a html tag as below.

```
<span id="createOrderFormId:accountNo" style="border-color: red;"><</span>
```

I need to read the style set for the property `border-color` so i used the following jquery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       var color = $('#createOrderFormId:accountNo').css('border-color');
        alert(color);
    });
```

But its not showing please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to escape `:` in selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vVpc/)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var color = $('#createOrderFormId\\:accountNo').css('border-color');
    alert(color);
});
```

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

**Edit** You can use native javascript property `style.borderColor` You can get DOM object from jQuery object use .get() or indexer. The native `getElementById` could be used with use escape character and this worked on **firefox** for me.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vVpc/18/)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    alert( $('#createOrderFormId\\:accountNo')[0].style.borderColor);
    alert(document.getElementById('createOrderFormId:accountNo').style.borderColor);   
});
```

Comment: The alert box is empty in firefox in chrome its showing rgb(255,0,0). I think the script gets loaded before page completed loading plz help.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, mavericks

Comment: The alert box it gives you rgb(255,0,0)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me solving the issue and understand metacharecters.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working in firefox, then you should try to get the individual sides of borders.

example:

```
 var color = $('#createOrderFormId\\:accountNo').css('border-top-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine here except span id `createOrderFormId:accountNo` as you mentioned double column `:` it is different meaning in jquery selector. It denotes type of element so here it is not treated whole string as id. remove double column, It will will work for you.

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm
```